# Can't call Postgresql function which should return text value

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

I have a little problem when calling a Postgresql function in Delphi with FireDAC.
The Postgresql function has the following definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."pgpDecryptMe" (
  todecode text
)
RETURNS text AS
$body$
DECLARE
  PGPPrivate TEXT;  
BEGIN
...
```

So it expects a "text" value and returns a "text" value.
I can call it with a long text parameter (over 900 character) and it returns the correct value in any sql admin tool without any problems.

```
select "pgpDecryptMe"('c1c04c030...a378624e6a659a20765') as Decrypt
```

But calling it in Delphi with the following code:

```
PGQuery.SQL.Text := 'select "pgpDecryptMe"(:test) as testvalue';
PGQuery.ParamByName('test').AsString := 'c1c04c030...a378624e6a659a20765';
PGQuery.Open();
```

Gives me the following error message:

```
[FireDAC][DatS]-2. Object [id] is not found
```

I googled and searched here but can't find any solution for the problem.
It is probably something very small I can't see :-(

I am working with Delphi XE7 and PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I got it working.
It looks like it needed an additional index field name which doesn't really make sense because it just returned one value...

So it worked when I changed my code to the following:

```
PGQuery.SQL.Text := 'select "pgpDecryptMe"(:test) as testvalue';
PGQuery.ParamByName('test').AsString := 'c1c04c030...a378624e6a659a20765';
PGQuery.IndexFieldNames := 'testvalue';
PGQuery.Open();
```